# jQuery Freetile Plugin Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a block of div (with a class `.feeds`) contents that have the width of 250px each but the is determined by the content, which are dynamic. want them displayed like what is obtainable in [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com) but with just two columns. This is working fine but each div has a pull down button which display hidden comments when clicked. When you click the pull down button, it hides the comment behind the next div. I want the next to shift down to wherever the last comment might stop but it not working.

I Have tried changing the `z-index` of the clicked div 1000, it works fine but I can't get the position of the next div to be relative to clicked one.

```
<div class = 'rows'>
  <div class='feed_blocks'>
    <div class='feeds'> <!-- this is iterated many times -->
      <!-- dynamic content goes here... -->
         <div class = 'morecomments'> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.feeds {
    background-color: rgb(235,243,243);
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 17.9333px;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.feed_blocks').freetile(); //Freetile plugin
$(".feeds").on('click', '.morecomments', function () {
            $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('.feeds').css('z-index', '1000'); // this is working
    $this.parents('.feed_blocks').closest('.feeds').css('position', 'relative'); // this is not working
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can u create a fiddle?